# Composer update fails with "drush/drush 9.6.0 requires symfony/yaml ^3.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[3.4.x-dev]"

Tags: composer-php, drush

I have a custom installation of Drupal that is managed by Composer. I executed `composer outdated`

That displayed some outdated packages. (see below)

I picked symfony/yaml and executed `composer require symfony/yaml`

[image]

My question is this: How do I resolve "Problem 1" shown in the screenshot. 
I assumed "-> satisfiable by...symfony/yaml v4.3.0" and ran `composer require symfony/yaml:v4.3.0`

Still more errors... very much the same.

Answer (score 0):

The package `drush/drush` requires a `v3.4.x` version of `symfony/yaml` and thefore conflicts with your request to update `symfony/yaml` to version `4.3.x`.

There are simple solutions as `drush/drush` is a development tool.

1. Remove the `require-dev` dependency to `drush/drush` ...

   ```
   composer remove 'drush/drush'
   ```

   ... and install the `drush` cli globally:

   ```
   composer --global require 'drush/drush'
   ```
2. Even better: Use a tool like [composer-bin-plugin](https://github.com/bamarni/composer-bin-plugin) to circumvent the dependency conflict in your global requirements:

   ```
   composer remove 'drush/drush'
   composer --global require bamarni/composer-bin-plugin
   composer --global bin drush require 'drush/drush'
   ```
3. Further options to install `drush` globally without dependency conflicts are tools like [cgr](https://github.com/consolidation/cgr) or phar.io's [phive](https://phar.io).

More information about this topic can be found in `composer/composer` issue [#5390](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5390).